# Why does the compiler expect ")" where I've put "," in my function declaration?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, turbo-pascal

In my AS-level computing course we're using Turbo Pascal, and for extension work I've been given the task of making a Blackjack/21 style card game. I decided to make a unit for general card game data structures:

```
unit CardLib;

interface

type
    CardSuite = (clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades);

    Card = record
        name:String;
        value:Integer;
        suite:CardSuite;
    end;

    CardDeck = object
        cards: Array[0..51] of Card;
        freeIndex: Integer;
        constructor init;
        procedure addNewCard(suite:CardSuite, name:String, value:Integer);
        procedure addCard(c:Card);
        function drawCard:Card;
        destructor done;
    end;

    CardHand = object
        cards: Array[0..51] of Card;
        freeIndex: Integer;
        constructor init(deck:CardDeck, size:Integer);
        function getLowestTotal:Integer; {Aces are worth 1}
        function getHighestTotal:Integer; {Aces are worth 11}
        procedure addCard(c:Card);
        destructor done;
    end;
...
```

I'm compiling this code with Free Pascal in Turbo Pascal compatibility mode, but I'm getting the following error:

```
CardLib.pas(18,39) Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "," found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcarm returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled)
```

If I comment out the addNewCard procedure, I get the same error in the CardHand constructor instead. Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use semicolons to separate the parameters.

```
procedure addNewCard(suite:CardSuite; name:String; value:Integer);
```

Comment: That would make sense, I think the var keyword would cause the parameters to be passed as references, which could be desired behaviour for me, but if I use the var keyword I still get the same error.

Comment: I know semicolons are used to end statements but can they be used as a separator here? That's all I got when it comes to guessing.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! Slightly confusing because parameters of the same time can still be grouped with commas (a,b,c:Integer) and also parameters are passed with commas. I'm used to ActionScript 3 syntax so I assumed that commas would be used for normal procedure declarations too. Cheers, feel free to make an answer for this.